# Laravel - get top 5 of multiple relationships

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have a user, a gallery and a log. the relationships are like this:

user has many galleries
galleries have many logs.

I would need to retrive the 5 most recent logs, from any gallery, that belong to this user. What confuses me is how can I put all galleries toghether and take the top 5 from all them toghether?

Comment: please share relevant code

Comment: Try something like:
User::with('galleries', 'logs')->take(5)->get();

Comment: You could get all the user's galleries and extract just the gallery id's, then do a query on the logs where galleryId is in the list of gallery id's you got previously, then sort by date desc, and limit to 5

Comment: @ChristopheHubert there isnt much code to post.. I simply have those relationships and need to get that data..

Comment: @NapsterAhmed logs has a relationship with galleries, but not with users..

Comment: @coedycode was hoping for something more simple..

Comment: perfect case for https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your relationship are as following:

```
users
    id - integer
    name - string

galleries
    id - integer
    user_id- integer
    name - string

logs
    id - integer
    gallery_id - integer
    title - string
```

You can use hasManyThrough Relationship (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the logs for the user.
     */
    public function logs()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Log', 'App\Gallery');
    }
}
```

You can then retrieve the last logs using:

```
    $logs = User::whereHas('logs', function($query){
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    })->get();
```

**EDIT**

You can't restrict the number of logs taken in the relationship. A workaround is to load the requested constrained relationship separately as explained here: 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18014

You can update your User Model:

```
/**
 * Limit the relationship to only include 5 results
 */
public function onlyFiveLogs()
{
    return $this->logs()->take(5);
}
```

And then for each $user, you can load the relationship manually:

```
$users->each(function($user) {
    $user->load('onlyFiveLogs');
});
```